# How to fix "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Int64Dtype' " error in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to execute a code, but i am getting an error.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, 4], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
```

I expect the output as:

```
Out[14]: 
0        1    
1        2    
2       NaN    
3        4

dtype: Int64
```

Comment: What is your pandas version? Because in pandas 0.24.2 working nice.

Comment: Can confirm it's broken in 0.23.4 and works in 0.24.2.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to wrong installation or older version as I tried the same and it's working

Answer (score 0):

try using np.int64 by importing numpy as np
or you can also try by typing `pip install --upgrade pandas` in your terminal or command prompt